# How to assign date to new date object

Tags: javascript

I want to assign date to new date object. when I am using it is not giving correct result http://jsfiddle.net/Cqw5c/

```
new Date (12/12/2012)
```

Comment: I have date in var like var mydate= 12/12/2012. How to pass mydate as string as date object i am using d= new date(mydate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getD() {
var d = new Date("12/12/2012");
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day   = d.getDate();
var year  = d.getFullYear();

alert( month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                }
```

---

Update

HTML:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  var thetestdate = $('#testdate').val();
  mynewdate = getD(thetestdate);
  alert(mynewdate);
});
```

JS:

```
function getD(mydatevariable) {
var d = new Date(mydatevariable);
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day   = d.getDate();
var year  = d.getFullYear();
var wholedate = ( month + "-" + day + "-" + year);
return wholedate;
                               }
```

Comment: I have date in var like var mydate= 12/12/2012. How to pass mydate as string as date object i am using d= new date(mydate)

Comment: Just updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

Quote the argument:

```
var d= new Date("12/12/2012");
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cqw5c/1/). You're currently creating a date with the result of the expression `12/12/2012`, which is three numbers and two division operators:

```
console.log(12 / 12 / 2012); // 0.0004970178926441351
```

Comment: Please stop answering duplicates instead of marking them ;)

Comment: @plalx - I find it quicker and more helpful to the OP to answer the question when it's such a simple one. If a duplicate then appears I always vote to close as well.

Comment: Perhaps it's faster but it pollutes SO and doesn't condition people to search before asking. (I did not downvote btw)

Comment: @plalx - I don't think it pollutes SO since the question will get closed as a dupe anyway. True about conditioning people to search before asking though. Here is not the place for this discussion though, I think it's been brought up on meta several times (where your approach does tend to be the accepted one I admit).

Comment: @plalx - Also, just closing as a dupe doesn't explain to the OP what's going wrong in their particular case.

Comment: You can always post a comment. I guess there could be cases where the question is complex enough to answer it even if it seems to be a possible duplicate, however it shouldn't be the norm.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new date based on

```
(12 / 12) / 2012 == 0.0004970178926441351
```

which will be some fraction of a second after January 1, 1970.

You can create a Javascript date by parsing a string:

```
new Date( "12/12/2012");
```

or by passing in individual components:

```
new Date( 2012, 12, 12 );
```

See [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) at MDN for more variations.